# Difference between suspended vs Terminated in SharePoint Workflow 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, workflow, workflow-settings

I want to know the difference between suspending and terminating SharePoint workflow.

Comment: one you can resume, one you have to restart. Suspended usually points to a permission error, terminated usually points to a critical failure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Terminated**  means terminate the workflow instance that is running. Once terminated, that workflow instance will be dead and will never be restart.

**Suspended** is something you can call resume workflow.

Msdn Links: [suspend](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.workflow.runtime.workflowinstance.suspend(v=vs.110).aspx)  and [terminate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.workflow.runtime.workflowinstance.terminate(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that terminate will unload the workflow instance and suspend does not unload the workflow instance.